# GET request works in development, not in production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, get

I have written the following script that should run a GET request to a specific URL when a set of checkboxes are ticked on and off.   It works perfectly locally but in Production, I get a 404 response.

Any idea why and how to fix it?

```
/**
* Remove all child nodes from an element
* @param {Object} element The element to empty
*/
function empty (element) {
    var children = Array.prototype.slice.call(element.childNodes);

    children.forEach(function (child) {
        element.removeChild(child);
    });

}

function toggleItem(toggler, itemType, itemUrl, itemState, itemSource) {
    let outputDiv = toggler.parentNode.querySelector('.theme-park-item-toggler-output');
    empty(outputDiv);

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', itemUrl);
    xhr.send(null);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) { // 4 means "Done"
            if (xhr.status === 204) { // 204 means processed successfully with no content returned
                console.log('success');

                if (itemState == true) {
                    let img = document.createElement('img');
                    img.src = itemSource;
                    outputDiv.appendChild(img);
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Failure to toggle');
                toggler.toggleAttribute('checked');
            }
        }
    };
}

document.addEventListener("turbo:load", function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.theme-park-item-toggler').forEach(function(the_toggler) {
        the_toggler.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
            toggleItem(the_toggler, the_toggler.dataset.type, the_toggler.dataset.url, e.target.checked, the_toggler.dataset.source);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: There must be something wrong with the `data-url` attribute. The console will show the full URL that it's trying to access.

Comment: @Barmar Just checked the URL, It's exactly what I need it to be

Comment: If it were then you wouldn't be getting a 404 error. That error means that the URL doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe you haven't deployed the script to the appropriate folder on the production server.

Comment: If this is still not working, and it obviously depends on how you have the script in your project: have you compiled or recompiled your assets recently, in production mode?

Comment: It's definitely deployed to the right place and the URL does exist. It gets recompiled each time i run and deploy the app.  I THINK its something to do with how rails responds to that controller action.  I need to research Rails 204 responses a bit more i think?

Comment: @Jad I've just converted it all to make a POST request instead and it's still failing in production.  Locally I've tested it and it comes back with a 204 response.  I've tested it in Postman and it's fine. When in production I get a 404 response.   Could it be a server issue?

Comment: Could it be because I am using Devise in my app and this endpoint is behind that?  If so then why does it work in Development?

Comment: You could try a `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` just to check. Errors and redirects using devise should be visible in the console. Any chance you can edit your question to include extracts from your log output?